# Is there a way to create classic pages on modern sites with Sharepoint Online?

Tags: search, modern-experience, classic-experience

I've been building an intranet at work using Sharepoint, and I've been trying to figure out how to have a larger search bar on modern web pages, like you could on classic pages with the Search Bar web part. I read that modern pages have no such equivalent web part, so I was wondering if instead I could create classic pages that use classic web parts on modern sites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description, it seems that you want to use both the modern pages and classic pages in SharePoint Online.

If yes, I think you can achieve that via he following steps.

a. Navigate to a library.

b. Click Return to classic SharePoint>Settings>Site contents>Site Pages>New to create a classic page.

c. If you click Settings>Add a page, you can still create a modern page.

Comment: Not sure why you were down-voted but up you go. I'm working in a classic environment but with the push of "Team Site" and "Team Site (Classic)" I wanted to play with the optimizations and see how much performance gain we could get. By going to the library and creating a page it immediately went into classic. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, this still works.

Answer (score 1):

**Could I create classic pages that use classic web parts on modern sites?**

**Unfortunately**, it's **not** supported to add a **classic web parts** on modern pages!

---

**These customizations are currently not supported for "modern" pages:**

- Adding "classic" web parts on "modern" pages
- Custom CSS via AlternateCSSUrl web property
- Custom JavaScript embedded via user custom actions (see note on SharePoint Framework Extensions)
- Custom master pages (more extensive branding will be supported later using alternative options)
- Minimal Download Strategy (MDS)
- Modern pages inside of the Site Template package (Save site as a template)

For more details, check [Customizing "modern" site pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages)

Comment: I think you didn't get the question completely, he doesn't want to use classic web parts on modern sites, rather to be able to add a classic page into a modern site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is fairly straightforward.

Pick a library (e.g. Site Assets), configure **Library Settings** | **Advanced settings** and set **Allow management of content types** to **Yes**.

For that library, within **Library Settings** under Content Types, click **Add from existing site content types**.  Select **Web Part Page** from **Available Site Content Types**.

This will allow you to create classic web part pages in your modern site.

*BEFORE*

[image: Before update]

*AFTER*

[image: After update]

Answer (score 0):

I can't yet reply or comment (or even vote?) on other's posts, but Dave Schmidt's reply is more helpful generally. For folks using a communication site, the "Return to Classic Sharepoint" doesn't appear because the Quicklaunch is a top bar and not the side nav of the typical site. If you have a commmunication site, Dave Schmidt's answer here is what you'll need to do to get a classic page.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/116863)